# RStudio and R 2.14.0, installing sp and rgdal

Tags: r, rstudio, rgdal

In the process of installing and getting the packages sp and rgdal running in my RStudio Version 0.98.501 on my Mac OS X 10_7_5, I get this error message:

```
Error: This is R 2.11.1, package 'rgdal' needs >= 2.14.0
```

However if I look at on the RStudio website the version 0.98.501 is the latest and should be up to date with R 2.14. Do I need to de-install any old versions? How would I do that?

Comment: You're running a really old (3+ years) version of R. You may want to consider updating, since we're now on to R 3.1.0.

Comment: You're also running an old version of your operating system. I'd suggest you upgrade to mavericks.